# Is it possible to embed the Power BI app service in a .NET Web App, similar to how MS Teams displays Power BI?

Tags: .net, reporting-services, powerbi, integration, powerbi-embedded

I would like to embed the Power BI service in the .NET web application. Similar to how MS Teams displays Power BI inside the application, I want users to be able to create new reports using existing data sources from .net web app instead of going to the https://app.powerbi.com/

Is this feasible, and do you have any suggestions on how to achieve this?

I have explored various options with Microsoft documentation, but most of them focus on embedding reports rather than the entire workspace or app service itself. My objective is to enable users to create reports based on existing data sources within the embedded environment.

Comment: Embedding also allows reports to be created and edited. [Create, edit, and save an embedded report](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/overview/powerbi/create-edit-report-embed-view?tabs=embed-for-your-customers)

Answer (score 0):

I think the best you can do is:

1. Use [PowerBI REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/) in order to create report, add add datasource and share it with an individual
2. [Set up the infrastructure to provide embed token for a user](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embedded/embed-tokens?tabs=embed-for-customers)
3. [Then Use `powerbi-client` JS library in order to embed that into your page.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/overview/powerbi/)
4. When you enter 'edit' mode, the user will have roughly the same experience as in the app.powerbi.com. [You can check that yourself in the playground.](https://playground.powerbi.com/en-us/dev-sandbox) Click "Use Sample" and then drag from the left column the "Enter edit mode" action to the code. Hit Run button in the header to see the effect.